# Why aren't cookies implemented as a map (key-value pairs)?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, cookies, browser

I have been using cookies for the authentication flow of my app and have been going through articles/questions on cookies and I've noticed that most people use cookies as a map (get value of given key or check if a given key exists). The question is why aren't they implemented as a map (key being the name and value being the object which has it's value and other information related to that cookie)?

With spring you get an array of cookies attached to the request, with JavaScript you get a string. Why not a map (or simply an object in the case of JavaScript)?

I know an individual cookie is implemented like a map but I'm talking about the set of all cookies here which you get using document.cookie in JavaScript or request.getCookies() in Spring.

Comment: I think legacy stuff. Storing the javascript object does not make sense and JSON was not way back then.

Comment: Yeah JSON having been introduced later would be the reason I suppose